# Why are constant sequences absorbed in the definitions of increasing and decreasing sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question is about *why* a definition is phrased the way it is.

> A sequence $(s_n)$ of real numbers is **increasing** if $s_n\le s_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and is **decreasing** if $s_n\ge s_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
>
> <sub>— Steven R. Lay, *Analysis With an Introduction to Proof*, 4th ed.</sub>

Notice that if $\forall n\in\Bbb N:s_n=s_{n+1}$ then a sequence is constant.  That means, according to this definition, any time I talk about an “increasing sequence,” I’m also including *constant* sequences (and the same with decreasing sequences).

Why would I want to by definition include constant sequences whenever I’m talking about increasing (or decreasing) sequences? Or is there another reason for that inclusion?

Comment: Why would you want to exclude them?

Comment: @Servaes I’m still a new student. But from my novice perspective, calling $(1)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ “increasing” is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Because increasing is usually defined in terms of partial orders, which usually use $\leq$ and $\geq$ as their default comparison operators (most definitions I've seen define $<$ and $>$ in terms of $\leq$ and $\geq$ in partial orders). We also have a term for increasing the way you intend it to mean, which is strictly increasing.

Comment: @DonThousand Would you consider expounding upon “partial orders” in an answer?

Comment: There is also the notion of *strictly* increasing/decreasing sequences. Neither includes constant sequences, but both also exclude all other sequences with repeated terms. Some authors prefer to use *non-decreasing* and *increasing*, instead of *increasing* and *strictly increasing*, which I find more descriptive myself (too).

Comment: @Servaes Is what I’m hearing you say that “Otherwise you’re excluding sequences with repeated terms”? If so, I’d accept that as an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is counterintuitive to call constant sequences both *increasing* and *decreasing*. When treating increasing and decreasing sequences, there are a few things to consider. Paraphrasing your definition:

**Definition 1:** A sequence $(s_n)$ is *increasing* if $s_{n+1}\geq s_n$ for all $n$, and *decreasing* if $s_{n+1}\leq s_n$ for all $n$.

The definition itself makes sense; such sequences are abundant and have nice properties, for example:

**Property 1:** An increasing sequences that is bounded from above converges.

So it is natural to give such sequences a name. Unfortunately this makes constant sequences increasing (and decreasing). There are two obvious ways to exclude constant sequences from the definition. An ad hoc solution would be:

**Definition 2:** A *nonconstant* sequence $(s_n)$ is *increasing* if $s_{n+1}\geq s_n$ for all $n$, and *decreasing* if $s_{n+1}\leq s_n$ for all $n$.

But this is rather ugly. Another solution would be:

**Definition 3:** A sequence $(s_n)$ is *increasing* if $s_{n+1}>s_n$ for all $n$, and *decreasing* if $s_{n+1}<s_n$ for all $n$.

This is not as ugly, but now we have also excluded many nonconstant sequences; all sequences that have repeating terms are excluded, even though they satisfy property 1. Also the Fibonacci sequence is excluded, for example, which I might like to call increasing.

But instead of trying to fix the definition, I would suggest to fix the terminology to better align with our intuition. Most authors use the following terminology:

**Definition 4:** A sequence $(s_n)$ is *strictly increasing* if $s_{n+1}>s_n$ for all $n$, and *strictly decreasing* if $s_{n+1}<s_n$ for all $n$.

And many authors, but certainly not all as your source shows, use the following more descriptive terminology:

**Definition 5:** A sequence $(s_n)$ is *nondecreasing* if $s_{n+1}\geq s_n$ for all $n$, and *nonincreasing* if $s_{n+1}\leq s_n$ for all $n$.

I can only recommend you do the same.